# Trying to read parquet file with pandas raise "Cannot yet unify dictionaries with nulls" error

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to read partitioned parquet files using:

```
df = pd.read_parquet(basepath_to_files)
```

However, this raises the error: `ArrowInvalid: Cannot yet unify dictionaries with nulls`.

Reading the very same data from a single (not partitioned) .parquet file does NOT raise the error.

How can I load this partitioned data?

Comment: Hello, any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably start with checking your `pd.__version__` to see where you are at in this. Then if you are above 2.0, adding argument `dtype_backend = ‘pyarrow’` looks like the first thing to try.

Relying on defaults settings might not be the best idea, especially since those have changed in relatively recent versions. Be sure to check out the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) if you haven't yet. That's too many references to null type to ignore:

- **use_nullable_dtypesbool, default False**

  - If True, use dtypes that use pd.NA as missing value indicator for the resulting DataFrame. (only applicable for the pyarrow engine) As new dtypes are added that support pd.NA in the future, the output with this option will change to use those dtypes. Note: this is an experimental option, and behaviour (e.g. additional support dtypes) may change without notice.
  - **Deprecated since version 2.0.**
- **dtype_backend{‘numpy_nullable’, ‘pyarrow’}, default ‘numpy_nullable’**

  - Back-end data type applied to the resultant DataFrame *(still experimental).* Behaviour is as follows:

    - "numpy_nullable": returns nullable-dtype-backed DataFrame (default).
    - "pyarrow": returns pyarrow-backed nullable ArrowDtype DataFrame.
  - **New in version 2.0.**